# Multiprocessing on a Dictionary of Class Instances

Tags: python-3.x, oop, multiprocessing

In the generic example below I use `Foobar_Collection` to manage a dictionary of `Foo` instances. Additionaly, `Foobar_Collection` carries a method which will  sequentially call `myMethod()`shared by all insances of `Foo`. It works fine so far. However, I wonder wether I could take advantage
of multiprocessing, so that `run_myMethodForAllfoobars()` could divide the work for several chunks of instances? The instance methods are "independent" of each other ( I think this case is called embarrassingly parallel). Any help would be great!

```
class Foobar_Collection(dict):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kw):
        super(Foobar_Collection, self).__init__(*arg,**kw)
    def foobar(self,*arg,**kw):
        foo = Foo(*arg,**kw)
        self[foo.name] = foo
        return foo

    def run_myMethodForAllfoobars(self):
        for name in self:
            self[name].myMethod(10)
        return None


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.result = 0
    # just some toy example method    
    def myMethod(self,x):
        self.result += x
        return None

Foobar = Foobar_Collection()
Foobar.foobar('A')
Foobar.foobar('B')
Foobar.foobar('C')
Foobar.run_myMethodForAllfoobars()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use `multiprocessing` for this situation, but it's not great because the method that you're trying to parallelize is useful for its side effects rather than its return value. This means you'll need to serialize the `Foo` object in both directions (sending it to the child process, then sending the modified version back). If your real objects are more complex than the `Foo` objects in your example, the overhead of copying all of each the object's data may make this slower than just doing everything in one process.

```
def worker(foo):
    foo.myMethod(10)
    return foo

class Foobar_Collection(dict):
    #...

    def run_myMethodForAllfoobars(self):
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            results = pool.map(worker, self.values())
        self.update((foo.name, foo) for foo in results)
```

A better design might let you only serialize the information you need to do the calculation. In your example, the only thing you need from the `Foo` object is its `result` (which you'll add 10 to), which you could extract and process without passing around the rest of the object:

```
def worker(num):
    return num + 10

class Foobar_Collection(dict):
    #...

    def run_myMethodForAllfoobars(self):
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            results = pool.map(worker, (foo.result for foo in self.values()))
        for foo, new_result in zip(self.values(), results):
            foo.result = new_result
```

Now obviously this doesn't actually run `myMethod` on the `foo` objects any more (though it's equivalent to doing so). If you can't decouple the method from the object like this, it may be hard to get good performance.

Comment: Indeed, I can decouple my method like you propose. Thank you for the hint and help. Am I correct to assume, that mp automatically "divides" the dictionary in chunks? With regard to your answer, I think the `for loop` contains a lil error (`new_result`)? However, I mad it work for myself.

Comment: Whoops, I left out a `zip` call, which matches up the results with the `foo` objects.

Comment: I just thought about another short related question. I want to call `.run_myMethodForAllfoobars(arg)` in a for loop over a list of args? Do you know wether the child processes are properly garbage collected after each iteration?

Comment: If you use a `with` statement to handle the `pool`, it will call `pool.terminate()` when it exits the indented block. That should shut down the worker processes. If you want to make sure they've all been cleaned up before progressing, you could call `pool.join()` afterwards (otherwise they might still be in the process of shutting down while your code continues to run).

Comment: Thx for the hint, I appreciate.